# JavaFX: Custom css property

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx

How can I add custom css properties like `-fx-accent` or `-fx-base`.

I've tried a naive way:

```
.root {
    -fx-small: 20;
}

.button {
    -fx-font-size: -fx-small;
}
```

Unfortunaly, I've got:

> WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration CSS Error parsing file:/home/ark/Projects/FXTest/out/production/FXTest/a.css: Expected '< number>' while parsing '-fx-font-size' at [6,15]

Comment: Are you trying to create a variable -fx-small that equals 20? You may consider looking into LESS instead of CSS. It allows for variable declaration so you could do this.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm looking for the way javafx handle it. I need to find out how -fx-accent property is set in caspian.css.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566210/declaring-variable-in-javafx-css-file) says only colors are allowed as variables in css.  Use something like LESS as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I never use the -fx prefix for global definitions. For me it is working like it is shown on slide 32: http://de.slideshare.net/ClaudineZillmann/lets-get-wetbestpracticesforskinningjavafxcontrols

Maybe there is a bug with the number format. Have you tried 20.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFX custom CSS-Variables does not support numbers!
You can just define custom colors.

```
.root {
    -fx-color: red;
}

.button {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-color;
}
```

Sry bro, maybe in a future release..
Happy coding,
Kalasch