# Change one color [global] color during runtime in javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx

As far as I understand you can [define "color variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566210/declaring-variable-in-javafx-css-file) in the css.

Let's say, I have a color called "default-background-color", and I set all backgrounds to be this color.

```
-default-background-color: #d0d0d0;
[...]
.button{
    -fx-background-color: -default-background-color
}
```

Then, during runtime, I want to change this color to be something else, so that all backgrounds change to my new color.

How is this achieved without reloading a new css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change set the style programmatically on any node to change the value of the looked-up color. The new looked-up color value will propagate to all child nodes. So, for example

```
root.setStyle("-default-background-color: #d0d080;");
```