# JavaFX CSS: How to inherit background color from other CSS settings?

Tags: java, css, javafx, background-color

I have a CSS file to set styles in JavaFX `TabPane` and `Tab`.

Is there a way to set the `TabPane`'s background color and inherit `Tab` background colors?

If I set the `tab-content-area` background color, can I pick this up for the tab without having specifically nominate the color again?

```
.tab-content-area 
{
  -fx-background-color: #d9d9d9; /* I want to apply this color to tab background */ 
}

.tab:selected 
{
  -fx-background-color : -fx-something; <?? what do i put here??>
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1;
  -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit more digging and found the answer to the  question [Declaring Variable In JavaFX CSS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566210/declaring-variable-in-javafx-css-file) allowed me to create a solution that works good enough for what I need.

My css now looks like this:

```
* {
    -fx-my-global-color:#d9d9d9;
  }
.tab-content-area 
  {
  -fx-background-color: -fx-my-global-color;  
  }

.tab:selected 
 {
  -fx-background-color : -fx-my-global-color;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1;
  -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the background of the `Tab` `transparent` or `inherit`:

```
.tab-content-area {
   -fx-background-color: #d9d9d9; /* I want to apply this color to tab background */ 
}

.tab:selected {
  -fx-background-color : transparent; /* Or: -fx-background-color : inherit;*/
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 1 0 1;
  -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0;
}
```

You can check the CSS structure for `TabPane` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane).

To learn more about named colors in JavaFX please refere to [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor).

Documentation of `inherit` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeinherit).